# Adobe AIR desktop application communicate with Processing application

Tags: sockets, air, processing, serversocket, osc

I have a Processing application that must talk to a desktop Adobe AIR application.
Can anyone suggest the best options considering the following?

If sockets are the answer, which type of Socket, UDP(Datagram Class), ServerSocket or just plain Socket?

-both apps reside on same machine
-latency important, smaller better
-signals being sent are small, consisting of 3 values

-communication is 1 way only, processing TO Adobe AIR

Answer (score 1):

On the Processing side you can use [oscP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/):

```
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 osc;
NetAddress where;

void setup() {
  frameRate(25);text("click to send\nOSC",5,50);

  osc = new OscP5(this,12000);
  where = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",8082);
}
void draw() {}
void mousePressed() {
  OscMessage what = new OscMessage("/straps");
  what.add(193.4509887695313);
  osc.send(what, where); 
}
```

In AIR you would use a [DatagramSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) indeed. Luckily you can use something that with OSC packets like [TUIO AS3's UDPConnector](http://code.google.com/p/tuio-as3/source/browse/trunk/org/tuio/connectors/UDPConnector.as). Here's a basic as3 sample:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    import org.tuio.connectors.UDPConnector;
    import org.tuio.osc.*;

    public class BasicOSC extends Sprite implements IOSCConnectorListener
    {
        private var oscSocket:UDPConnector;
        private const OSCSERVER:String = "127.0.0.1";
        private const PORT:int = 8082;

        public function BasicOSC()
        {
            try{    
                oscSocket = new UDPConnector(OSCSERVER,PORT);
                oscSocket.addListener(this);
                trace(this,"OSC ready");
            }catch(e:Error){    trace(e.getStackTrace());   }   
        }
        public function acceptOSCPacket(oscPacket:OSCPacket):void{
            //handle OSC here
            var message:OSCMessage = oscPacket as OSCMessage;
            trace("message from :",message.address,"at",new Date());
            for(var i:int = 0; i < message.arguments.length; i++)
                trace("\targs["+i+"]",message.arguments[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is roughly what I used for some of [these projects](http://www.hirschandmann.com/2013/siemens-crystal/):
[image: Hirsch&Mann Prevent Fires for Siemens Crystal]
[image: Hirsch&Mann City Monitor for Siemens Crystal]

Comment: hello, I used your answer, but when doing in a 1/30 second 25 message (each kinect body point as one message) the osc receiver slows down...  is there a way to flush or check all messages in the queue?

Comment: @bluelemonade Feel free to vote for the answer it it was useful ;)
I haven't plaid with AIR in a while so I'm out of the loop if there were changes to how sockets are handled and if performance dropped from one version of AIR to another. It's hard to tell where the bottleneck is without seeing the whole project. One thing I'd try is sending a single message with 25*3 floats (25 joints with x,y,z) and seeing if that performs better. The other thing I can think of is trying [airkinect](http://as3nui.github.io/airkinect-2-core/). I haven't tried it myself but keeping it all native might work :)