# OSC communication in flash-flosc vs TUIO

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an AIR app that need to communicate via OSC with a remote server.

I'm somewhat confused by the differences between this 'Flosc' AS3 library
https://code.google.com/p/flosc/

and TUIO AS3
https://code.google.com/p/tuio-as3/
since they both allow OSC communication.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is TUIOAs3 simply more powerful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the last updates have been around 2011 on both.

I think FLOSC is slighly older and relies on running a UDP Server for OSC connectivity which then is bridged to as3 via the [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) class(which is TCP)
This bridge is the java application available on the FLOSC repository download list. On OSX they recommend Memo's [udp-tcp-bridge](https://code.google.com/p/udp-tcp-bridge/).

tuio-as3 includes OSC support which you need and the nice thing about it is that it can also make use of AIR's udp functionality, so you won't need the java or c++ UDP to TCP Bridge.(the simpler the better, you'll have to worry about 2 apps being configured properly, not 3 as you would with FLOSC)

I'd recommend tuio-as3 if you're not sure, especially since you already have a [basic as3 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202572/adobe-air-desktop-application-communicate-with-processing-application) from last year (which I hope was helpful).